# How to benchmark asynchronous operations with JMH

Tags: java, jmh

I'm trying to benchmark an asynchronous operation that has the form:

```
void op(Callback cb);
```

I could benchmark using:

```
@Benchmark
void issueOp(BenchState state) {
    state.svc.op(nullCb);
}
```

but that only measures the time to issue the operation, not the completion time.

```
@Benchmark
void issueOp(BenchState state) {
   final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
   Callback signalCb = new Callback() {
       public void complete() {
           latch.countDown();
       }
   };
   state.svc.op(signalCb);
   signalCb.await();
}
```

does measure the completion time, but with only one op queued up at a time.

I would really like something like:

```
@AsyncBenchmark
void issueOp(BenchState state, final BenchmarkCompletion bc) {
    Callback cb = new Callback() {
        void complete() {
            bc.complete();
        }
    };
    state.svc.op(cb);
}
```

where BenchmarkCompletion is something provided by JMH to indicate that the operation is complete.

Is there anything like this in JMH?

Comment: How about benchmarking `cb.complete()`? This is a *micro* benchmarking framework, not an integration test framework.

Comment: I want to do a  _milli_ benchmark, not an integration test.
Per the jmh page: "JMH is a Java harness for building, running, and analysing nano/micro/milli/macro benchmarks written in Java and other languages targetting the JVM."

For example, what if I wanted to benchmark AsynchronousFileChannel ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20long,%20A,%20java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler) ) ?

there is nothing to benchmark in cb.complete() since all the work happens before the completion is called.

Comment: I see. I was trying to suggest synchronously executing the operation, but I didn't understand your API. As a more familiar example, if I had `Runnable` that, in my application, I submitted to an `Executor`, for JMH I would invoke it's `run()` method directly. Is something like a `Runnable` created inside the `op()` method, and submitted to a executor?

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this:

```
  final private val OperationsPerInvocation = 10000
  @Benchmark
  @OperationsPerInvocation(OperationsPerInvocation)
  def schedulePeriodicallyBenchmark(): Unit = {
    val latch = new CountDownLatch(OperationsPerInvocation)
    timeServiceScheduler.schedulePeriodically(Duration.ofMillis(100)) {
      latch.countDown()
    }
    latch.await(20, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
  }
```